# Call to undefined method Tipo::orderBy() Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have created a new migration (called 'tipo'), with its Model and Controller. And I also have created its Views... I have done exactly in the same way that I have done it before. In fact, I have copied and pasted mostly of the code. Everything else works perfectly.

But when I want to access to my 'tipo/index', I got the next message:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Call to undefined method Tipo::orderBy()
```

I have read some possible solutions, and I've already updated my controller. And I also have the same error... Argggg!!!

MY CONTROLLER: TipoController.php

```
class TipoController extends AdminController {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     * GET /tipo
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $tipos = Tipo::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
        return View::make('tipos.index')->with('tipos', $tipos);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     * GET /tipo/create
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('tipos.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     * POST /tipo
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        // var_dump($input);

        $v = Validator::make($input, Tipo::$rules);

        if ($v->passes()) {

            $tipo = new tipo;
            $tipo->nombre = Input::get('nombre');
            $tipo->descripcion = Input::get('descripcion');
            $tipo->m_desc = Input::get('m_desc');
            $tipo->slug = Str::slug(Input::get('nombre'));
            $tipo->user_id = Sentry::getUser()->id;
            $tipo->save();

            // return $tipo->user_id;

            return Redirect::route('tipos.index');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     * GET /tipo/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $tipo = Tipo::where('slug', $id)->first();

        $date = $tipo->created_at;
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Europe/Madrid');
        $date = $date->formatlocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

        return View::make('tipos.show')->with('tipo', $tipo)->with('date', $date);
    }

    public function myShow($id, $slug)
    {
        $tipo = Tipo::where('id', $id)->first();

        $date = $tipo->created_at;
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Europe/Madrid');
        $date = $date->formatlocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

        return View::make('tipos.show')->with('tipo', $tipo)->with('date', $date);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     * GET /tipo/{id}/edit
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $tipo = Tipo::where('id', $id)->first();

        $date = $tipo->created_at;
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Europe/Madrid');
        $date = $date->formatlocalized('%A %d %B %Y');

        return View::make('tipos.edit')->with('tipo', $tipo)->with('date', $date);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     * PUT /tipo/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $input = array_except(Input::all(), '_method');

        $v = Validator::make($input, Tipo::$rules);

        if($v->passes())
        {
            Tipo::find($id)->update($input);
            return Redirect::route('tipos.index');
        }

        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($v);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     * DELETE /tipo/{id}
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Tipo::find($id)->delete();

        return Redirect::route('tipos.index');
    }

}
```

And my Model: Tipo.php

```
class Tipo extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array(
        'nombre' => 'required',
        );

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you post your Model code?

Comment: <?php

class Tipo extends Eloquent {
 protected $guarded = array();

 public static $rules = array(
  'nombre' => 'required',
  );

 public function user()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id');
 }
}

Comment: Hmm... Your Model looks OK, can I see your Controller please? Please can you post via http://pastebin.com to make it easier to read?

Comment: Sorry... I don't know how it exactly works, but this is the url where you can see the code: http://pastebin.com/0y1MyeMc

Comment: Have you run composer update?

Comment: Yes, I have. And I have the same problem... :S

Comment: Use reflection on the Tipo in order to check what file it refers to. That's where the problem lies I suppose.

Comment: Oh wait - have you called your controller `Tipo` aswell? or is it called `TipoController`?

Comment: My controller is called TipoController.php

Comment: Can you edit and post your FULL contoller and FULL model into your question.

Comment: I don't understand you when you say 'use reflection on the Tipo'... what do you mean?

Comment: Is your migration class also named `Tipo`? You should rename it to `TipoMigration` or something.

Comment: My migration class is called 'Tipo', in the same way I have done before, and it has worked to me...

Comment: But if you are not using namespaces (which you said you are not) and you have two classes of the same name - that is probably your problem. I would rename your migration to `TipoMigration` and then run `composer update` and see if that fixes your problem. If not - as @deczo said, you need to reflect and inspect the `Tipo` to see what is is *actually* calling. The whole problem here is `Tipo` is not what you think it is, it is another class elsewhere in your code that is not `eloquent` - which is why `all()`, `orderBy()` etc are failing.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I've changed 'Tipo' to 'TipoMigrate' and... it works!!! I don't understand why, but it works!! Thank you very very much!!! ;)

Comment: @JaviZu Check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php It lets you do this: `$ref = new ReflectionClass('Tipo'); $ref->getFileName(); // path to the class file` and much more useful things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using namespaces (which you said you are not) and you have two classes of the same name - that is your problem.

so in one place you have

```
class Tipo {}
```

which is your migration. In another place you have

```
class Tipo extends Eloquent {}
```

which is your model.

But both classes are called `Tipo`.

So later on, when you call `Tipo::all()` - Laravel does not know which class to call, because you have 2x `Tipo`.

You can solve this by either using namespaces, or renaming your migration to `TipoMigration`.

Comment: The Shift Exchange's solution worked perfectly... but finally I've found my error.

I created my migration in singular (php artisan migrate:make **tipo**) and I should have wrote **tipos**. I've changed that and I've solved the problem too. Without renaming my Class.

Again, thank you to The Shift Exchange and Deczo for their help!!